# Creating VMs from a VM template and linking with Chef server

Tags: chef-infra, vmware, vsphere

I have setup a Chef Server (running version 12.0.1)

I now have a windows machine setup which can talk to the Chef server.

My question is after I turn this into a template how do I get any new server created using the template to run "chef-client" to sync itself with the Chef server?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [chef-client provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_client.html) for Vagrant?

Otherwise I don't get your question.

Comment: This VM template is stored in vSphere

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case, doesn't it? What's with that windows machine, what role plays it? Your question is unclear to me.